# Rename all files with the same extension and any name

Tags: rename

I need to rename all files with `.js` extension, but names of files can vary, for example:

```
rootDirectory
--firstDirectory
----first.js
--secondFileDirectory
----second.js
--thirdDirectory
----third.js
```

Needs to be renamed to

```
rootDirectory
--firstDirectory
----newName.js
--secondFileDirectory
----newName.js
--thirdDirectory
----newName.js
```

Is there a way to do it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What operating system and version are you using?

Comment: @StephenHarris Harris Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ububtu 14 has a version of `find` that has the `-execdir` option, so this becomes relatively simple:

```
find . -name '*.js' -execdir mv -i {} newName.js \;
```

For example, I have this tree:

```
./A
./A/first.js
./B
./B/second.js
```

I run the command

```
$ find . -name '*.js' -execdir mv -i {} newName.js \;
```

The resulting tree:

```
./A
./A/newName.js
./B
./B/newName.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Perl `rename`, assumes `pwd` is rootDirectory:

```
rename 's|(.*/).*\.js|$1newName.js|' */*
```

or

```
rename 's|.*/\K.*\.js|newName.js|' */*
```

- use `rename -n` if you want to check how the renaming will happen